# How do I apply a /gamerule before opening a world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just downloaded a really cool lobby map, but I noticed hot air balloons with fire, and lava decoration with wood. Pretty soon everything was on fire :(. I know the `/gamerule doFireTick` command, but I don't have time to use it before everything catches on fire. Is there any way to change the gamerule without getting on the single player map?

Comment: Have you tried Copy-and-Pasting the command in the moment you can? Seems like an easy solution.

Comment: You can edit the level.dat by hand, I believe.

Comment: You know, that is a good idea FEichinger, and thanks for your kindness towards me being a noob, but theres still not that long before everything is on fire and I get the command pasted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use NBTExplorer to open `level.dat` of the world, then change `GameRules/doFireTick` from `true` to `false`.

[image]

Comment: @Whale_Maniac If this answer worked for you, accept it by clicking the tick mark to the left of it. You'll earn reputation!